# Insert each div inside next div (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I insert `div.one` into his next `div.two` with jquery?

**What it is:**

```
<div id="list">
 <div class="box one"></div>
 <div class="box two"></div>
 <div class="box one"></div>
 <div class="box two"></div>
 <div class="box one"></div>
 <div class="box two"></div>
</div>
```

**What I want:**

```
<div id="list">
  <div class="box two">
    <div class="box one"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box two">
    <div class="box one"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box two">
    <div class="box one"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**What I tried (but it insert all `div.one` in every `div.two`):**

```
$("#list .box.one").each(function() {
    $(this).prependTo(".box.two").next();
});
```

Whats my fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```js
$("#list .box.one").each(function() {
    $(this).prependTo($(this).next());
});
```

using the class in the `preprendTo()` function will of course select **all** the `.box.two` elements, instead by doing `$(this).next()` we only get the very next sibling element.

Comment: Damn, I also tried $(this).next(), but I missed the "()" around of this + next. I am getting old. Thx 4 help!

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
$("#list .box.one").each(function (index) {
    $(this).prependTo($("#list .box.two")[index]);
});
```